React Route Configuration: Component Not Rendering Despite Correct URL Update
I'm experiencing an issue with my React application where the SearchResults component fails to render data despite the URL being correctly updated based on the search query. When I search for a query (e.g., Dermatologist), the URL updates as expected (e.g., http://localhost:3000/SearchResults?q=Dermatologist), but the component doesn't display any results, and the console remains empty.
The code was intended to display the fetched results. However, although the URL updates according to the query made, the results are not being displayed. My React application utilizes React Router for navigation, and I have a SearchResults component designed to showcase doctor details based on a search query provided in the URL. Despite the URL updating correctly based on the search query, the SearchResults component fails to render the doctor details, and no errors or logs appear in the console.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout/Layout";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const SearchResults = () => {
  const [doctors, setDoctors] = useState([]);
  const location = useLocation();
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const specialization = searchParams.get("q");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDoctors = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/v1/fetch/searchQuery/${specialization}`);
        setDoctors(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching doctors:", error);
      }
    };

    if (specialization) {
      fetchDoctors();
    }
  }, [specialization]);

  return (
    <Layout title="Search Results">
      <div>
        <h4>Doctor Details</h4>
        <div className="table-container">
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Experience</th>
                <th>Specialization</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {doctors.map((doctor) => (
                <tr key={doctor._id}>
                  <td>{doctor.name}</td>
                  <td>{doctor.phone}</td>
                  <td>{doctor.gender}</td>
                  <td>{doctor.location}</td>
                  <td>{doctor.experience}</td>
                  <td>{doctor.specialization}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;




Are you saying that the SearchResults component itself isn't rendered? How and where is SearchResults rendered? Please [edit] to include a complete and relevant [mcve] of the code you are working with.

When I search, the URL changes according to the search query, but despite having the data related to that query in the backend, I'm not able to fetch and display it.

Sorry, that didn't really answer my question. I'm asking if you have issues rendering this SearchResults component, or if it's rendering just fine and SearchResults has issue rendering its content. Do you understand the difference? If it's the former then we need to see what/where/how SearchResults is rendered and how the URL is updated/etc, and if it's the latter then we need more specific details what the issue is in SearchResults.

React recommends that you don't write your own data fetching from scratch. Data fetching is a part of React Router as of version 6.4.
As described here, you can use a loader for data fetching. You can then use that data in the component as described here. You likely need to migrate how you set up your routes too, which is described here.
If you want to learn the basics of data fetching before following that advice, you can use Chrome dev tools to inspect what is going on in your component.

Check Network tab to inspect what was fetched from your api.
Download React Developer Tools extension. This will allow you to inspect state in your components.
If all else fails, add logging to your happy path as well.

